# Undefined Behavior Caused By The roll() Function (Using C)

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

I am meant to have a program that takes an array of elements from a user, and outputs the array in a different sequence with the `3rd` element taking the place of the `1st` and the `1st` and `2nd` element moving down `1` element position. 
Here is the expected input/output:

```
Enter the array length: 7  
Enter the elements in the array: 5 3 4 9 8 7 2
```

The output of the array `a2` should then be:

```
The output array is: 4 5 3 9 8 7 2
```

However, when I compile and run my source code, I get this as the output:

```
25 0 -617353404 32766 4196318 0 -1
```

Now I know it has something to do with the `roll()` function causing undefined behavior. However, I am not sure exactly what I must change in the `roll()` function to deter this from happening.

Also keep in mind that I may **only** use pointer arithmetic within the `roll()` function (in the main is fine).

What should I do next to make sure my code accurately modifies the `a2` array while simultaneously using pointer arithmetic so that it prints the values in the `a2` array correctly in the main function?

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2);

int main()
{
    int s, i; 
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    int a1[s], a2[s];
    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

    for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a1[i]);
    }
    a2[s] = a1[s];
    roll(a1, s, a2);
    for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    int *p, *q; 
    int *r, *s, *t; 
    int *u, *v, *w;
    p = a1 + n;
    q = a2 + n;
    r = a1;
    s = a1 + 1;
    t = s + 1;
    u = a2;
    v = a2 + 1;
    w = v + 1;

    u = t;
    v = r;
    w = s;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The only initialization of `a2` is `a2[s] = a1[s];`, which uses the index `s`  which is out of bounds. You never initialize the actual contents of `a2`.

Comment: As for your `roll` function, what is it supposed to do? Right now it isn't doing *anything* really.

Comment: It is meant to change the order of the array elements in a1 and then modified a1 would be the array a2. The third element of a1 takes the first position in the array and then the 1st and 2nd fill in the 2nd and 3rd positions. This modified array would then be a2.

Comment: And for the initialization, I was trying to get the array a2 to have the same user-entered elements that were assigned to a1.

Comment: Regarding the `roll` function. That's not what you're doing. All you do is assign a lot of pointers. You never actually "roll" anything. "Rolling" means to save one element, then [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) the remaining elements, and restore the saved element in its new place. And you copy an array with [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  For the posted code, the compiler outputs 4 warning messages about variables being set but not used AND the `roll()` function has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: this does what you state you want to do:  `int temp = al[2]; al[2] = al[1]; al[0] = temp;`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  In the posted code, the check would be: `if ( ... != 1 ) { // handle error }`

Comment: in function: `main()` this statement: `a2[s] = a1[s];` results in undefined behavior because in C, the offsets into an array have the range 0...<number of elements in array -1>.  Also, that statement only copies a single element.  To copy the whole array use: `memcpy( a2, a1, sizeof(int)*s);`

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  However, names like `s` and `al` and `a2` are meaningless, even in the current context

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not sure what to do. For example, there is no need to assign:

```
 a2[s] = a1[s];
```

What is even more problematic here that you are reaching beyond array boundaries invoking undefined behaviour.

Your `roll` function is not doing anything useful.
You need to deference the pointer to actually access the element of your array.

The solution is simpler that you imagined. Deal with `3` elements of your array `a1` first and copy the rest of the array `a1` to array `a2`.

> Also keep in mind that I may **only** use pointer arithmetic within
>   the `roll()` function.

Sure, but array `[]` operator is nicer and `memcpy` would be potentally faster.

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void roll1(int *a1, int n, int *a2);

int main(void)
{
    int s, i; 

    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    int a1[s], a2[s];

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

    for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a1[i]);
    }

    roll1(a1, s, a2);

    for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

//  5 3 4 9 8 7 2
//  4 5 3 9 8 7 2
void roll1(int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    // array subscription: 
    // 1.
    //a2[0] = a1[2];    
    //a2[1] = a1[0];
    //a2[2] = a1[1];

    // or pointer arithmetic: 
    // 2.

    //(*a2)   = *(a1+2);    
    //*(a2+1) = *(a1);
    //*(a2+2) = *(a1+1);

    // 3. OR
    int * a1p = a1;
    int * a2p = a2;

    int a2_0 = *a1;
    int a2_1 = *(++a1p);
    int a2_2 = *(++a1p);

    //printf("%d %d %d\n",a2_0,a2_1,a2_2);

    *(a2p)     = a2_2;
      ++a2p;
    *(a2p)     = a2_0;
      ++a2p;
    *(a2p)     = a2_1;

    // now the rest:
    //1.
    // memcpy(a2+3, a1+3, sizeof(int) * (n-3) );  

    //2. or  
    //for(int i=3; i<n; i++){
    //    *(a2+i) = *(a1+i);
    //} 

    //3. OR
    for(int i=3; i<n; i++){
       *(++a2p) = *(++a1p); 
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Enter the size of array: 7                                                                                                                   
Enter the elements of the array: 5 3 4 9 8 7 2                                                                                               
4 5 3 9 8 7 2
```

Comment: I run this code and it works perfectly, it just does not use pointer arithmetic in the for loop of the roll function. I realize now that I didn't specify, but the for loop is supposed to use pointer arithmetic only without using indexing with i. Do you possibly have an example of this?

Comment: @MannyDeJesus No problem :). The example has been updated.